# How do I prepare this floor for tiling?

Tags: floor, tiling, renovation

I want to renovate this bathroom in a 1970s house in central europe. I want to tile the floor, but I don't know what foundation I need for that. The floor consists of several plywood sheets which are loose and wobbly, so completely unsuitable. There is also some water damage around the toilet. Underneath the sheets are wooden beams crossing the room in regular intervals, and the space between the beams is filled with what looks and feels like substrate balls used in planting pots.

I clearly need to replace all of the plywood, but I don't know what to put in place instead. Should I remove the filling between the beams? Replace it with something else? And what comes on top?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those "substrate balls" - are they rocks or something else? If they're something else, could you perhaps supply the name of them in your native language (Central Europe indicates native tongue <> English) and we'll try to find a machine translation that might be more helpful. In general, though, firmly attached 3/4" (~18mm) plywood or [OSB](https://www.apawood.org/osb) is usually a good basis for tiling.

Comment: That kinda looks like particle board, or possible some kind of OSB.  Can you get us a closer pic of the subflooring?

Comment: The substrate balls are "Expanded clay aggregate". It is used as an lightweight insulation and filler material (normally under the screed or mixed with mortar). I don't know if its ok to use between wood, but it isn't totally wrong. A common brand is "Leca"

Comment: What is under the wooden beams? Do they rest on concrete or are they the load-bearing element of your floor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if those balls aren't some type of insulation?? If your floor was cold then you could remove them and add new insulation if not they are doing their job and I would leave them. Unless they smell bad from the leaking toilet.

You will have to remove the toilet to change out the failed wax ring and repair the wood under it as well.

Plywood or OSB subfloor with **Ditra uncoupling and waterproofing membrane** over it will provide a good foundation for your ceramic tile.

https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Membranes/Uncoupling-%28DITRA%29/Schluter%C2%AE-DITRA-%26-DITRA-XL/p/DITRA?facets=false

Be sure to use a tile designed for flooring applications.

Comment: re: [balls as insulation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/264886/how-do-i-prepare-this-floor-for-tiling#comment539386_264886)